# How to get the current number of cells in a sheet using Google AppsScript?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a tool to get the current number of cells in a sheet using Google AppsScript? By "number of cells", I am referring to the 5-million number-of-cell limits per sheet in Google Sheet. To start off, what is "number of cells"?

For example, if `isblank()` on `A1` and `B3` of the first tab of a sheet (ie. file) gives `TRUE` respectively, and `FALSE` on any other cell (and other tabs), would `range.getValues().length` on `Sheet1!A1:B3` produce the current "number of cells" for the sheet?

I am hoping to avoid the error

> Exception: This action would increase the number of cells in the workbook above the limit of 5000000 cells.

by creating a new sheet (ie. file) every time "number of cells" approach 5000000.

The second part is how to get "number of cells" efficiently. Especially if there is no direct tool, how does one query "number of cells" efficiently, so that the query can be a (small) part of a script that runs ~100 times a day and still falls within the execution time limit of a (free) personal account? (I am hoping to run my script without impeding other scripts under an organization's domain.)

Comment: I think `number of cells` is pretty descriptive. It does not matter if they are empty or not, this limitation is about the **number** of the cells. However, the performance of the spreadsheet file relies on other parameters as well. Consider deleting unnecessary columns rows and sheets.

Comment: How about getMaxRows() x getMaxColumns()

Comment: @soMario: If it did not matter whether a cell is "empty", then how many cells would be there in a fresh, brand new, "empty" sheet?

Comment: @Cooper: I'll need to experiment with that. Thanks for chiming in. So far, I found in a sheet where adding new blank rows via the GUI would prompt the error, among other actions such as duplicating a tab, adding content to individual cells anywhere does not prompt the error. I know GoogleSheet initializes with iirc 5000 rows and 52 columns, leaving open with the possibility that `getMaxRows()` x `getMaxColumns()` is checked against 5M. So I plan to experiment with tallying `getMaxRows()` x `getMaxColumns()` across all tabs and see if that yields a number that gives some clue.

Comment: @soMario: I tried deleting an empty column via GUI. Indeed, as a result I am able to add more rows. That points to `getMaxRows()` x `getMaxColumns()`. Logging off for the night though. Will try to find something out tomorrow. If you have more thoughts, please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Hi guys, it seems "number of cells" indeed refers to `.getMaxRows()`x`.getMaxColumns()` and that max "number of cells" is 4804640.

Answer (score 1):

Prompted by comments, the following experiments provide an answer.

In a sheet where the following actions via the GUI prompts the error in the OP,

- Adding any number of new columns or rows, including on a tab that has not changed its original `.getMaxRows()` and `.getMaxColumns()`, ie. 1000 rows x 26 columns. (Will refer to this as "reference tab".)
- Adding new tabs

adding content to any cells currently displayed in the GUI does not prompt the error.

The sum of `.getMaxRows()`x`.getMaxColumns()` for all the tabs in this sheet yields 4804640.

Further, deleting a column in reference tab permits the addition of 40 rows via the GUI after which adding a 41st row would prompt the same error. Of course, 1 column with 1000 rows has the same number of cells as 40 rows with 25 columns.

Thus, it seems "number of cells" refers to `.getMaxRows()`x`.getMaxColumns()` and the max "number of cells" is 4804640. (+/- 25 cells, technically.)

In order to query current "number of cells", one can first [use `getSheet()`](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/134812/142901) and then tally `.getMaxRows()`x`.getMaxColumns()`. This is fast because `getSheet()`, `getMaxRows()`, `getMaxColumns()` are built-in and fast.